# Getting a dropdown list populated +sending value back

Tags: php, html

So I was busy with my php and I ran into a problem I populated a dropdown list but how do I get the value back that the user selected?

```html
<?php

echo "Please select the date:";
echo "<select id=data name=data>";
for($i = 0; $i < $leng; $i++)
{
 echo "<option value=$date[$i]>$date[$i]</option>";
}

echo"</select>";
$selected_key = $_POST['data'];
$selected_val = $date[$_POST['data']];
echo $selected_key;
echo $selected_val;
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: create a form..

Comment: thanks @FastSnail. I'm new to php and html so how can I do it with a form. I understand that <form action="search.php" method="POST"><input type="submit" value="submit" name="action"></form> but how do I create the dropdown-list over to html? I take it you use the input name and call it in php?